# Playing Audio Files - Toolkit Not Initialized

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to play an audio file in java but it says the toolkit is not initialized, I'm not sure what toolkit I'm suppose to use nor where to initialize it.

```
new PianoKey(getClass().getResource("/noteDir/octave" + octaveNumber + "/G"+ octaveNumber + ".wav").toString(),octaveNumber);
```

piano key class:

```
public class PianoKey {
        public PianoKey(String keySoundPath, int octaveNumber){
            try{
                Media audioPath = new Media(keySoundPath);
                MediaPlayer audioPlayer = new MediaPlayer(audioPath);
                audioPlayer.play();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

throws

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
```

Comment: `Media` and `MediaPlayer` are JavaFX classes, and so they require that the JavaFX toolkit be started. Is this part of a JavaFX application that is launched from an [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) subclass?

Comment: Its just a standard java application on netbeans.

Comment: To use JavaFX objects, you need to start the JavaFX toolkit, which you do by following the JavaFX application lifecycle. (Essentially, you have to code your application as a JavaFX application.) See the docs I linked in the previous comment.

Comment: Thankyou, and is this the only way to play audio files or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Never mind thats easy enough, over estimated the amount of restructuring it'd need. Put it as a comment and I'll be happy to accept the answer :D